# Passing encrypted password in mount command

Tags: command-line, mount, password, security, encryption

I am trying to cron a simple 4 line bash script to backup a folder which requires me to mount the NAS folder for which I have to provide the password.
Which is a big NO , Is there a way to pass the password in encrypted form or atleast a safe way.

I am trying to mount a NAS folder which requires the password, how to encrypt or make it secure.

```
sudo rsync -arltvu --progress /media/VAULT/Pictures/ /media/Pictures/  -o username=admin,pass=passphrase
```

Comment: Are you concerned about storing the login & password in plain text on your computer, or about sending them over the internet un-encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing "passphrase" with "$(mypassphrase)", to run the program/script mypassphrase for providing the pass phrase at the run time of the cron command line.

Comment: So `mypassphrase` would ask you to type in the passphrase, and repeat it on stdout? I think I read about some ways stdin & stdout can be overheard by other programs/users, but on a single user ubuntu machine it's probably pretty secure

Comment: If the NAS requires username and password on the rsync command, then there's no hiding of the password; it'll be available in /proc for the process, although you'd need to be root to access it of course. I merely imagined a "mypassphrase" program that picked up the password from somewhere safer; just avoiding it be in clear text in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used `rysnc`, I can't say for sure that this will work, but I would try using a `credentials` file (the following is summarized from [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)).

Create a file called `.nascredentials` containing

```
username=admin
pass=passphrase
```

and having the appropriate permissions (600 suggested).

Pass `credentials=/path/to/.nascredentials` instead of `username=admin,pass=passphrase`.